# latex formatting negative number with brackets/parenthesis

Tags: format, latex, brackets, negative-number

In expressions, I use Latex macro such as \a to have '23' or '-23'.

The problem I have is that \a-\a produces '23--23' instead of '23-(-23)' as it should, when \a is negative.

I tried the numprint package that allow to change the minus sign in red but couldn't use the trick to convert \np\a into '(-23)' when \a is negative.

Comment: So do you have `\def\a{-23}` and you want `\a` to print `(-23)`? One could condition on the value contained in `\a` and print `(-23)`, but that would be independent of what precedes or follows it. That is, `\np{\a}` would print `(-23)` and `\np{\a}-\np{\a}` would print `(-23)-(-23)`.

Comment: In fact I use luaLaTeX and variables : as an example, let's say we have three variables a=-1,b=-2,c=-3 and let consider aX^2-bX-c . Ideally, I would like to transform what I get today -1X^2--2X--3 (incorrect) en -1X^2-(-2)X-(-3). It is an intermediate step for pedagogical purposes, Afterwards, I use a formal engine, Xcas, to go further. I am looking for something simple. Otherwise I can imagine some sort of \ifthenelse for each number that adds () to negative numbers or even a lua functions that does the job.